# AngularJS ng-click - передача строки со спец. символами, как параметр

Tags: angularjs, функции

```
<div class="video" ng-click="startVideo('<iframe width="750" height="380" src="<?php echo $link;?>?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');"></div>
```

Пример не работающего кода **Error: $parse:lexerr
Lexer Error**
Как правильно передавать строку со спец. символами в функцию. ну как я понимаю здесь проблема в `'` и `"`. Как экранировать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вложенные кавычки должны быть экранированы с помощью обратного слэша: `\'` или `\"`

Конкретно в данном случае должны быть экранированы вложенные двойные кавычки

```
<div class="video" 
     ng-click="startVideo('<iframe width=\"750\" height=\"380\" src=\"<?php echo $link;?>?rel=0&autoplay=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>');">
</div>
```